# NodeJS, MongoDB findOne with paremeter and the date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I get error when I add another `{  }` after `{ad_id: advertisement._id}`. How to handle this??

Error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: >1 field in obj: { $lte: new Date(1551205719440), $gte: new Date(1551202119440) }`

```
    let adContacts = await AdvertisementContact.findOne({ad_id: advertisement._id}, {
        "created_at": {
            "$lte": moment().toDate(),
            "$gte": moment().subtract(24, 'hours').toDate()
          }          
    });
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could fix this.

Comment: Second parameter is for projection. If you want to filter the documents with created_at then use inside the first argument. `let adContacts = await AdvertisementContact.find({
  "ad_id": advertisement._id
  "created_at": {
    "$lte": moment().toDate(),
    "$gte": moment().subtract(24, 'hours').toDate()
  }          
})`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Worked! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try enclosing both filter criteria in one single object:

```
let adContacts = await AdvertisementContact.findOne({
ad_id: advertisement._id,    
"created_at": {
    "$lte": moment().toDate(),
    "$gte": moment().subtract(24, 'hours').toDate()
  }          
});
```

The problem with your implementation is that you are sending two parameters to `findOne`, according to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) first parameter is filter, second parameter is projection.

Comment: @abraom_185 make sure you mark this as answered so other users can profit from this answer too